# Excluding rows based on criteria SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am looking for some help in figuring out how to remove all rows where column 1 = a if column 2 also = a.

It is quite difficult to describe, so I will use an example below.

```
1    2
a    b
a    a
a    null
b    c
b    e
c    c
d    f
d    a
d    e
```

The table above is what currently exists, I am looking to write a query which gives the following result

```
1    2
b    c
b    e
d    f
d    a
d    e
```

If any of them match, i.e. column 1 = a column 2 = a, then all rows where column 1 = a should be removed. Is there any way to do this?

TIA

Comment: I'm a bit baffled why "c" is not in the result set.

Comment: because c = c and I am trying to exclude all rows where they match

Comment: @BeckyPurland first row a  b should also be appear in the result set.

Comment: @SurajKumar no it shouldn't, I want to exclude all rows where column 1 = a if column 2 has matched with any of column 1. please read again, it's very difficult to describe

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want rows where `col1` has not rows where `col1 = col2`.  If that is a correct interpretation, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                        t2.col1 = t2.col2
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `<> (not)` operator.

```
Select * from Yourtable where [Col1] <> [Col2] and Col1 <> 'a'
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ab1b2ff3f01903746707c0b0b2e3d7d) demo.

Comment: This only excludes the ones which match, this isn't what i've asked for

Comment: If any of them match, i.e. column 1 = a column 2 = a, then all rows where column 1 = a should be removed.

Comment: @BeckyPurland Check the modified query now.